# Python converting a time string into ticks?

Tags: python, time

Is there an easy way to convert a string showing date/time data into a Unix tick value?

I have date/timestrings in some files of data that I am downloading using a python script direct from a national meteorology centre.

The string is in the format yearmonthdayhourminutesseconds e.g. 20170108233000.

I can easily break that into nicely formatted strings but is there any way to convert it into ticks as that would be useful for sorting, eliminating duplicate data etc.?

I was thinking about a simple yearticks=(year-1970)*(365*24*60*60) but that does not take into account leap years and leap seconds.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: So which part of this are you stuck on? Turning that string into a Python `datetime` object (`.strptime(...)`) or getting the Unix timestamp from that object (`.timestamp()`)?

Comment: I don't think there's anything in Python that tracks leap seconds. If that's a real requirement you're going to have some trouble.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) Unix time ignores leap seconds, so in that regard it's the same as Python. Good thing too, because a library that kept track of leap seconds would be extremely difficult.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you parse it into a `datetime` object and then calculate the number of seconds between Januari 1, 1970 and that moment:

```
import datetime

d = datetime.datetime.strptime( "20170108233000", "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
t0 = datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=timezone.utc)
ticks = (d - t0).total_seconds()
```

**EDIT**:

or you can, as @jonrsharpe suggests, use the `timestamp` method immediately:

```
d.timestamp()
```

Running this on my machine produces:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import datetime
>>> 
>>> d = datetime.datetime.strptime( "20170108233000", "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
>>> t0 = datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)
>>> ticks = (d - t0).total_seconds()
>>> ticks
1483918200.0
>>> 
$ date -d @1483918200
Mon Jan  9 00:30:00 CET 2017
```

Notice that this produces January 9, 2017. But this is belgium time.

Comment: There's a `timestamp` method, you don't need to calculate the start point yourself!

Comment: @jonrsharpe: thanks for the suggestion. However for some reason if I do this in the interpreter, it gives an error?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: `AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'timestamp'`

Comment: Ah - *"New in version 3.3"*

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Yeah I found out myself concurrently :s, was running Python 2.7.* for some reason, apologies :(.